# Unix Proxifier? [W7/Ubuntu]

Tags: windows, socks, pre-tor-proxy

I'm currently running Tor on Windows 7 with [Proxifier](http://proxifier.com/) and there I can set up that certain websites will connect through certain ports that's connected with Tor:

[image: proxification rules in proxifier]

That means that each time I go to http://google.com I get one IP and if I set up another rule for example: http://ebay.com and port 9153 it will use that another IP.

So I can go to google.com and ebay.com at the same time using different IP's.

Now I'm wondering if there is any software that can do that on Unix?
I've been trying with proxychains but I can't seem to find that feature.

Thank you